# How to increase display size?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, monitor, 20.10

I have a dual monitor setup with one 1080p and one 1440p monitor. The size of text and graphics on my 1440p monitor is very small. I have tried to use the scale option but it reduces the sharpness of the monitor. Is there any way to avoid that/fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use GNOME Tweaks Tool/Unity Tweaks Tool

Fonts > Scaling Factor